# Setting outgoing IP address in open-uri with RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, open-uri

I'm new to open-uri and trying to set an outgoing IP address using open-uri in ruby on rails. I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6420362/end-of-file-error-when-trying-to-get-response-from-a-url-and-parsing-the-json-wi) as a reference to get started. I'm porting an app from PHP where I could use CURLOPT_INTERFACE in curl_setopt. What's the best way to do this using open-uri in rails? (Doing this from the controller - not command line.)

If there's not a way to do this - any suggestions on an alternative to open-uri? My goal is to take in and parse JSON data.

Comment: `open-uri` is not a CURL bindings, there is a `curb` gem, that might have such feature.

Comment: @taro: I'm trying to find the best way in rails to do a function similar to the curlopt_interface option. I'll check out curb.

Comment: Here are the docs: http://curb.rubyforge.org/classes/Curl/Easy.html#M000015

Comment: Not sure the interface is setting correctly using Curb. I've opened a ticket on the [curb git page](https://github.com/taf2/curb/issues/102).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from your questions is you want to hit another server from a specific IP which suggests you have a server with couple of addresses.

What I can suggest you is try to execute curl directly and do what you want to do or use a wrapper for it.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like open-uri can do this. But with `net/https` it's fairly easy.

```ruby
require 'net/https'
require 'json'
uri = URI('https://jsonvat.com/')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.local_host = '1.2.3.4'
http.use_ssl = true
request = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/')
request.content_type = 'application/json'
request.initialize_http_header('Content-Type' => 'application/json')
response = http.request(request)
json = JSON.parse(response.body)
```

Probably you don't need the "require" lines inside Rails Controllers. 
You can specify the outgoing IP address with the `http.local_host` line.

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24896074/1371731
- https://yukimotopress.github.io/http